# Is there a limit to how much swap can be used?

Tags: ram, swap

I have an old computer (which I still use despite its issues) that only has 3.5GB usable RAM (no idea where the other 0.5 went, but assuming it's for BIOS and shared graphics memory).
It used to have 3.8GB or so of swap partition.

I have since run out of memory a few times, and increased the size of the partition to 15.8GB. It shows this as the amount of available swap in htop and system monitor now, and it loads on boot and all that. It seems to be working fine.

Oddly, it doesn't seem to be able to actually use more than 3.8GB (the original size) or so of the swap. What could be causing this?

It's an old computer with a [Pentium Ironlake P6100](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/50175/intel-pentium-processor-p6100-3m-cache-2-00-ghz.html) dual-core CPU. Is there a memory limit I am running up against even with it being swap and not ram?

Comment: Is your processor 32-bit? If so, does your processor support PAE?

Comment: What are you doing to use all of RAM? I had a 4GB system that never used swap. But then I was using a laptop with only 1.5GB of RAM. So I learned not to open more than one large application and several small ones. When I would open two large apps or too many other apps, it would go to swap and be very slow.

Comment: The law of diminishing returns applies to swap; and still regularly use boxes with only 1.5gb of ram, but wouldn't want to use 15.8gb of swap anytime (oldfred's comment), I don't know if PAE applies but it would explain ~3.8gb

Comment: Your PC is 64-bit and supports PAE per the http://ark.intel.com link added to your question. 
 https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-swapspace#tb-recommended-system-swap-space is an authoritative article on swap recommendations, and suggests unless you use Hibernation, the optimum swap space equals your RAM size... What are the apps you use which run you out of memory?

Comment: Mostly a lot of tabs in Chrome, with an IDE or two. It's a 64-bit machine, which I would have assumed would let it have more memory... What is PAE and is that good or bad?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo blkid` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Which partition did you resize?